# How Can I Achieve 100% Width On Menu Li's

Tags: html, css

I have a mobile site using a mobile menu, I would like the li's to stretch the entire page at 100%. When I set this the menu shrinks and I can't figure why, max-width is also ignored but a set px width isn't. I've checked the elements and can't see where this width is being picked up from.

Here's the code

```
<div id="navbar">
<nav>
<div class="miniIconPanel">
<input type="radio" name="miniMenu" id="open">
<input type="radio" name="miniMenu" id="close" checked="checked">
<label class="labelOpen" for="open"></label>
<label class="labelClose" for="close"></label>
<div class="miniIcon"><b></b><b></b></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="">View Full Site</a></li>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="">Buyers Guide</a></li>
<li><a href="">Leather Care</a></li>
<li><a href="">Privacy &amp; Cookies</a></li>   
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navbar {
height:49px; 
background:rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
}

.miniIconPanel {
width:30px; 
height:23px; 
position:absolute; 
top:7px; 
left:10px;
padding:6px; 
border-radius:6px; 
background:#000; 
}

nav input {
display:none;
}

nav label {
width:400px; 
height:37px; 
position:absolute;
top:-1px;   
left:-1px; 
z-index:10;
margin:0;
}

nav div.miniIcon {
width:30px; 
height:13px; 
position:absolute; 
top:6px;  
left:6px; 
border:solid #d3d3d3; 
border-width:5px 0; 
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
transition:0.5s;
}

nav div.miniIcon b {
width:30px; 
height:5px; 
position:absolute;
top:4px; 
left:0; 
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
transition:0.5s;
background:#d3d3d3;
}

nav ul {
top:50px; 
left:0; 
list-style:none;
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
background:#f5f5f3;
}

nav li {
margin-bottom:10px;
}

nav li a {
width:100%;
display:block;  
color:#111; 
text-align:center; 
text-decoration:none; 
padding:8px;
border:1px solid #808080;
border-radius:6px;
background:#fafafa;
}

nav #close:checked ~ .labelClose {
z-index:5;
}

nav #open:checked ~ div b:first-child {
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}

nav #open:checked ~ div.miniIcon {
border-color:transparent;
}

nav #open:checked ~ div b:last-child {
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

nav #open:checked ~ ul {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: After noticing the menu icon didn't update. I revised both `html` and `css` in my answer. Let us know if it works.

Comment: That's spot on thanks, I've one more question if I may, the menu needs a left/right margin of 10px, I've set this in the nav ul (margin:0 10px) but the right hand side is being ignored.

Comment: Since the `<ul>` is `position:absolute;`, we have to 'fake' the margin withpositioning.  Do this: `nav ul{left:10px; right10px; width:auto;}`  What you interpreted earlier as 'ignoring' the style is really the element being wider than the screen... because its width is really the width+margin. Since the width is already 100%, the right side gets pushed off the screen. Hence we set the width to auto and then use `left` and `right` to give the appearance of margin. Oh, and make sure to leave <ul> left/right padding and margin at zero for this also. Style the `<li>` elements from there if needed.

Comment: That's great, I'm really grateful to you for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The arrangement of your HTML elements didn't agree with the CSS.**

Change HTML to this:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <nav>

        <input type="radio" name="miniMenu" id="open">
        <input type="radio" name="miniMenu" id="close" checked="checked">

        <div class="miniIconPanel">
            <label class="labelOpen" for="open"></label>
            <label class="labelClose" for="close"></label>
            <div class="miniIcon"><b></b><b></b></div>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">View Full Site</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Buyers Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Leather Care</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Privacy &amp; Cookies</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Fixes:**

`<div id="navbar">` was missing its closing `</div>` tag

`<ul>` was moved outside of `<div class="miniIconPanel">`

`<input id="open" />` was moved outside of `<div class="miniIconPanel">` to control its intended next CSS sibling, the `<ul>`

---

Then add this to the very bottom of your existing CSS to override your current CSS.  Although, you 'should' manually update your current CSS with these definitions.

```
/*  =====
    FIXES
    =====   */
nav #open:checked ~ div.miniIconPanel > div.miniIcon {
    border-color:transparent;
}
nav #close:checked ~ div.miniIconPanel > .labelClose {
    z-index:5;
}
nav ul{
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:auto;
}
nav ul li a{
    margin:auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav li a {
  width:282px; /*<- change this to 100%*/
  display:block;  
  color:#111; 
  text-align:center; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  padding:8px;
  border:1px solid #808080;
  border-radius:6px;
  background:#fafafa;
}
```

If you change this to 100% it should do the trick.

edit: okay it doesnt do the trick. . sorry

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use `position: absolute` inside a **div** with `position: absolute`. I did some changes in your CSS, and it is working. But you will need to style your miniIconPanel a little.

```
.miniIconPanel {
width: 100%;
height:23px; 
position:relative; 
}

nav div.miniIcon {
width:30px; 
height:13px; 
position:absolute; 
top:6px;  
left:6px; 
border:solid #d3d3d3; 
background:#000;
border-width:5px 0; 
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
transition:0.5s;
padding:6px;
border-radius:6px; 
}

nav ul {
top:50px; 
left:0; 
list-style:none;
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
background:url(http://leathersolutions.co.uk/mobile/images/background.jpg) repeat #f5f5f3;
width: 100%;
}

nav li a {
display:block;  
color:#111; 
text-align:center; 
text-decoration:none; 
padding:8px;
border:1px solid #808080;
border-radius:6px;
background:#fafafa;
}
```

You can check in working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vsLov8x8/).